# How to iterate through a vector of tuples using iterator or any other way in c++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, tuples

```
std::vector<std::tuple<PCWSTR, PCWSTR,PCWSTR> > tempVector;
tempVector.push_back({ L"temp", L"temp1", L"temp2" });
tempVector.push_back({ L"data", L"data1", L"data2" });

const ULONG fieldCount = tempVector.size();

PCWSTR fieldNames = new PCWSTR[fieldCount];
PCWSTR fieldValues = new PCWSTR[fieldCount];
PCWSTR fieldSize = new PCWSTR[fieldCount];   
int index=0;
for (std::vector<std::tuple<PCWSTR, PCWSTR, PCWSTR>>::iterator it = tempVector.begin(); it != tempVector.end(); ++it) {
        fieldNames[index] = it->_Myfirst;// I know this is incorrect code, how do I fetch the first value here..
        fieldValues[index] = it->second;  
        fieldSize[index] = it->third;           
        index++;
    }
```

Is there any other way I can iterate and populate these tuple values to an array...

Comment: `std::vector<std::tuple<PCWSTR, PCWSTR, PCWSTR>>::iterator` and the weekly award for "best case to use `auto`" goes to...

Comment: A [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) would be better than using an iterator manually

Comment: How to use auto, I did see a couple of examples, but not too sure...

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you point me to a link.. not sure how to use it..

Comment: @ccoding literally just swap that big long type name for `auto` and you're done.

Comment: @ccoding see the answer I have posted

Answer (score 2):

[`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) does not have named fields for its individual elements. But you can use [`std::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) to access them individually by index, eg:

```cpp
int index = 0;
for (std::vector<std::tuple<PCWSTR, PCWSTR, PCWSTR>>::iterator it = tempVector.begin(); it != tempVector.end(); ++it) {
    fieldNames[index] = std::get<0>(*it);
    fieldValues[index] = std::get<1>(*it);
    fieldSize[index] = std::get<2>(*it);
    ++index;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`std::tie()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) instead, eg:

```cpp
int index = 0;
for (std::vector<std::tuple<PCWSTR, PCWSTR, PCWSTR>>::iterator it = tempVector.begin(); it != tempVector.end(); ++it) {
    std::tie(fieldNames[index], fieldValues[index], fieldSize[index]) = *it;
    ++index;
}
```

Now, with that said, you can simplify that iterator declaration using `auto` instead, eg:

```cpp
for (auto it = tempVector.begin(); it != tempVector.end(); ++it) {
```

Though, you really should use a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead of a manual iterator loop, eg:

```cpp
size_t index = 0;
for (auto &t : tempVector) {
    // Either:
    fieldNames[index] = std::get<0>(t);
    fieldValues[index] = std::get<1>(t);
    fieldSize[index] = std::get<2>(t);

    // Or:
    std::tie(fieldNames[index], fieldValues[index], fieldSize[index]) = t;

    ++index;
}
```

And you really should be using `std::vector` instead of `new[]` manually, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<PCWSTR> fieldNames(fieldCount);
std::vector<PCWSTR> fieldValues(fieldCount);
std::vector<PCWSTR> fieldSize(fieldCount);
```